# Limit products using php

Tags: php, html

Actually I want limited no of products in page when the limit exceeds it should show products along with more button i.e, link. for eample products per page is 6 and if products are more than 6 means it should display more link button. How we can resolve it.

Below is my code,

```
<?php
if ($child['id'] == $product['parent_id']) {
    $count = 1;
    if ($count <= 1) {
        $count++;

        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
                <p><?php echo $product['name']; ?></p></a>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
}

?>
<span><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>">More..</a></span>
```

Comment: Is there a loop here?

Comment: Where is your loop?

Comment: what about doing that in the query ? you can count all column that match, and/or limit the number of results [MySQL count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) and [MySQL limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's a loop involved here, above your code. You're instantiating the `$count` variable everytime. Do it like this:

```
<?php $count = 1; ?>
<?php for(/*some loop*/) {?>
    <?php if($child['id'] == $product['parent_id']){?>
        <?php if($count <= 6) {
            $count++;
                ?>
        <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $product['href'];?>" ><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
        <p><?php echo $product['name']; ?></p></a>
        </li>
        <?php } else {
        ?>
            <span><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>">More..</a></span>
        <?php
            break;
        }?>
    <?php }?>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your code should probably have a conditional statement determining whether it should be displayed:

```
<?php if ($count > 6){ ?>
    <span><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>">More..</a></span>
<?php } ?>
```

**EDIT:** As others have pointed out, without a loop, your `$count` variable isn't much use...

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php if($child['id'] == $product['parent_id']){?>
<?php $count = 1; /// this should be out side of the loop 

  $count++;
  ?>
  <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $product['href'];?>" ><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
    <p><?php echo $product['name']; ?></p></a>
  </li>
  <?php if($count > 6) { ?>
    <span><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>">More..</a></span>
  <?php 
    break; //it will stop your loop to create more records
  }?>
```

Another solution is, if you are using database to display products then you can add limit in query to avoid full query e.g

```
SELECT * FROM prod_tbl LIMIT 0,6
```